# increments by 1 and add it with every created object?

Tags: java, oop

```
class MyObject {

static int instanceCounter = 0;

static int counter = 0;

MyObject() {

instanceCounter++;

counter = counter + 1;

}

}
```

I am using the static ints to get this output:

> Value of instanceCounter for Object 1: 5
>
> Value of instanceCounter for MyObject: 5
>
> Value of Counter for Object 1: 1
>
> Value of Counter for Object 2: 2
>
> Value of Counter for Object 3: 3
>
> Value of Counter for Object 4: 4
>
> Value of Counter for Object 5: 5

but its displaying

> Value of instanceCounter for Object 1: 5
>
> Value of instanceCounter for MyObject: 5
>
> Value of Counter for Object 1: 5
>
> Value of Counter for Object 2: 5
>
> Value of Counter for Object 3: 5
>
> Value of Counter for Object 4: 5
>
> Value of Counter for Object 5: 5

my runner class

```
class RunMyObject {

public static void main(String[] args) {

MyObject Object1 = new MyObject();

MyObject Object2 = new MyObject();

MyObject Object3 = new MyObject();

MyObject Object4 = new MyObject();


MyObject Object5 = new MyObject();

System.out.println(“Value of instanceCounter for Object 1: ” + Object1.instanceCounter);

System.out.println(“Value of instanceCounter for MyObject: ” + MyObject.instanceCounter);

System.out.println(“Value of Counter for Object 1: ” + Object1.counter);

System.out.println(“Value of Counter for Object 2: ” + Object2.counter);

System.out.println(“Value of Counter for Object 3: ” + Object3.counter);

System.out.println(“Value of Counter for Object 4: ” + Object4.counter);

System.out.println(“Value of Counter for Object 5: ” + Object5.counter);

}

}
```

and if i remove static this is what it displays

> Value of instanceCounter for Object 1: 5
>
> Value of instanceCounter for MyObject: 5
>
> Value of Counter for Object 1: 1
>
> Value of Counter for Object 2: 1
>
> Value of Counter for Object 3: 1
>
> Value of Counter for Object 4: 1
>
> Value of Counter for Object 5: 1

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Since instanceCounter is a static variable, all objects share the same variable. Since you are incrementing the instanceCounter during each object construction, at the end of creating  5 objects, its value is 5. 
Consequently you get the output as 5 in all your sys outs. Thats the point of static

**EDIT**
To achieve what you need, do the following:

```
class MyObject  {

    static int instanceCounter = 0;

    int counter = 0;

    MyObject() 
    {
        instanceCounter++;
        counter = instanceCounter;
    }

}
```

Comment: but what i want is instancecounter to store 5 in it but counter to store incremented value each time constructor is invoked.

required output:

Value of instanceCounter for Object 1: 5


Value of instanceCounter for MyObject: 5


Value of Counter for Object 1: 1

Value of Counter for Object 2: 2


Value of Counter for Object 3: 3


Value of Counter for Object 4: 4


Value of Counter for Object 5: 5

Comment: Raam your solution worked thanks a lot, please explain what you changed and why?

Comment: @Mansoor I made counter an instance variable. So that means that each object has its own variable called counter and the value stored in counter is specific to that object only. So what I did is to increment the static variable which is shared by all the objects at each object construction and then assign its value to the instance variable. Read this link for more details http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: @Mansoor Please accept the answer if you think it helped.

Answer (score 2):

You must be confused about the usage of `static variables`.

`static class variables` are created once per class. They are shared by all class instances where as `non-static class variables` are created for every object instance.

So if your `counter` variable is `static` it will be created only once and shared by all instances your class.

When you access it with `MyObject.counter` or `object1.counter` and so on, you are accessing the same `counter` variable as `static` variables can be accessed with a class name as well as with an instance variable.

And if it is `non-static` and every instance(or object) of your class will have its own copy of `counter`.
So each of your `Object1` , `Object2` and so on will all have their own `counter` variable.

And all of them will have value 1 and so you get 1 in the output.

UPDATE:

Change your code to get your desired output that you have mentioned in a comment of one of the answers:

```
MyObject Object1 = new MyObject();

System.out.println(“Value of Counter for Object 1: ” + Object1.counter);

MyObject Object2 = new MyObject();

System.out.println(“Value of Counter for Object 2: ” + Object2.counter);

MyObject Object3 = new MyObject();

System.out.println(“Value of Counter for Object 3: ” + Object3.counter);

MyObject Object4 = new MyObject();

System.out.println(“Value of Counter for Object 4: ” + Object4.counter);

MyObject Object5 = new MyObject();

System.out.println(“Value of Counter for Object 5: ” + Object5.counter);

System.out.println(“Value of instanceCounter for Object 1: ” + Object1.instanceCounter);

System.out.println(“Value of instanceCounter for MyObject: ” + MyObject.instanceCounter);
```

Comment: so there is no way i can display 1,2,3,4,5 and so on whenever i invoke constructor for only counter even if i remove static that is with counter?

Comment: see my updated answer and hope it will help you.

Comment: this did not worked, Raam's solution worked. :) but thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it like this, you should add another variable, i.e.:

```
class MyObject {

    int instanceCounter = 0;

    static int counter = 0;

    MyObject() {

        instanceCounter = counter;
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: i have already tried adding counter++; instead of counter = counter +1:but output was same as 1,1,1,1,1 for all objects.

Comment: But that's not the only thing I changed - I also made instanceCounter non-static, and I assign its value in constructor, and then I increment the static field.

Comment: can you tell me how to Store instancecounter's value in id, my sir told me that way i can display counter's value as 1,2,3,4,5..... with every object created and total number in instance counter?

Comment: result is still same 5,5,5,5,5.... for all created objects. but now instance counter has 0.