# How to add plus 1 to an existing number whenever the object is created within Java?

Tags: java, object, bluej

For example, I have this class named Member which basically creates a member    who can log into a website. 5 things need to be initialised within the constructor whenever an instance of this object are made, one of them is the membership number. This membership number has to be unique. An idea I had was to add plus 1 to the number whenever a Member object is created.

Here is my current code:

```
    public Member(String newEmail, int newMoney)
    {
    // Intialises the email.
    email = newEmail;
    // Intialises the membership number.
    membershipNumber = 000;
    membershipNumber =+ 001;
    // Intialises the login status.
    loginStatus = false;
    //
    companions = new ArrayList<Friend>();
    // Intialises the members money.
    money = newMoney;
    }
```

Please ignore the loginStatus, companions and money.

As you can see i've set a default value for the membership number to be 000, and for +1 to be added onto it, but every member created, now matter how many I make, the membership number is always 1.

I tried another method by adding a whole other field like:

```
   public Member(String newEmail, int newMoney)
   {
    // Intialises the email.
    email = newEmail;
    // Intialises the membership number.
    membershipNumber = membershipNumberTwo;
    membershipNumberTwo =+ 001;
    // Intialises the login status.
    loginStatus = false;
    //
    companions = new ArrayList<Friend>();
    // Intialises the members money.
    money = newMoney;
    }
```

But the membership number is always 0.

Can anyone help me out by making the membership number have +1 added to it whenever the member is created in the constructor?
Thanks.

Disclaimer: Im at beginner level of Java.

Comment: You dont need the preceding 0's for an integer. Just use `membershipNumberTwo += 1;`

Comment: What datatype is membershipNumber? Integer?

Comment: @MasterYoda Thanks, tried this but both members that I created have the membershipNumber 0. And yes, it is an Int

Comment: You have a typo. `=+` should be `+=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do this using numbers?
Instead, create a unique membershipNumber using UUID. This will keep uniqueness and you don't have to work hard for that.

Have a look at the [UUID class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html%20*UUID%20Class*) bundled with Java 5 and later.

use a random UUID you can use the [randomUUID](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID()) method.

---

Edit:
If you plan to create the objects in concurrency and still want the incremental memberId, just store an static AtomicNumber and use atomicNumber.incrementAndGet() to get the 'new' userID

See more [here](http://www.baeldung.com/java-atomic-variables)

---

As for the examples you gave:
In the 1st example - you initialise the value of membershipNumber within the constructor, which cause it always to be 1, like you described.

In the 2nd example, unless `membershipNumberTwo` is *static*, it'll be initialised every construction of a new class, so every time it'll be initialised to 0. You need to keep state between construction of one object to the other.

Comment: Thank you, your solution by making membershipNumberTwo static worked for me. I'll also try the UUID class and AtomicNumber solutions you gave.

Comment: Happy to help :) It's important for you to understand why the behaviour was the way it was. Try looking at different userId initialisation in constructors online

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the field static for the class so it's not instance bound. Make `membershipNumber` as a static field in your `Member` class.

Comment: Not really clear, if OP use the static field like this, every instance will share the value, it should use an member variable initialized with the static field to be more precise.

Comment: Tried changing membershipNumber from int to static int and made 2 members afterwards, both still have the memberhsipnumber of 0

Answer (score 0):

In example 1, you set the value to `0` then add `1`, so it is always `1`.

In example 2, I would guess `membershipNumberTwo` is not `static` so the value is `0` by default in each instance, giving you always `0`. Simply add a `static` modifier to that variable to store the value at the class level, not the instance level.

---

This is the most basic solution possible.

Simply use a static variable.
Use that value to initialize the member variable and don't forget to increment the static value on each constructor call.

```
class Member{
    private static int membershipNumberCount = 0;
    private int membershipNumber;

    public Member(){
        membershipNumber = membershipNumberCount;
        membershipNumberCount++; //Could be done on the same line but keep it simple
    }
    ...
}
```

This will not be persistent, the value will be reset on each execution of the application.

Comment: This worked, now every member i create gets +1 added to their membership number, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use static variables. try to use something like this.
one staic variable to store next MemberShip number and use that to find membership number for each new members while creating. [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431013/increments-by-1-and-add-it-with-every-created-object)

```
private static int NextMemberNumber = 1;
private int membershipNumber;
public Member(String newEmail, int newMoney)
{
// Intialises the email.
email = newEmail;
// Intialises the membership number.
membershipNumber =NextMemberNumber;
NextMemberNumber = NextMemberNumber + 1;
// Intialises the login status.
loginStatus = false;
//
companions = new ArrayList<Friend>();
// Intialises the members money.
money = newMoney;
}
```